# Where is my problem in start activity function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, layout

I'm new in Kotlin Developement. I'm trying to start a new activity from the `main` activity but the only thing it displays is a blank message after the toast message. But I really don't understand where the problem comes from.

Here's `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

    private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        item -> when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_home -> {
                //replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_search -> {
                replaceFragment(SearchFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_person -> {
                replaceFragment(ProfileFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.nav_favorites -> {
                replaceFragment(FavoritesFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }

        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home)

        if (!imgurClient.isConnected) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You are not connected.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intentToWebView = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intentToWebView)
        }

    }
}
```

Here's `LoginActivity`:

```
eclass LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

`Activity_login.xml` contains a `textview` which displays a text in white and the background is purple.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You've overridden the wrong method in your `LoginActivity`. It should be:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the correct onCreate method. It should be

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the correct [`onCreate` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) without the `PersistableBundle` as a second argument:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    }
}
```